# Ubuntu doesn't recognize the hardware of Vivobook pro

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hardware, asus, cpu

I have an ASUS Vivobook Pro, i7-7700HQ, NVidia GTX1050. I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS but I have some issues that I can't solve, I think they're related to the HW.

First, I have to run with `acpi=off` or it hangs during boot. This solves the boot but at shut down it hangs at the end of the process (I'm not the only one with this problem, I haven't found any working solution).

Secondly, this is the output of lscpu

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               900.122
CPU max MHz:           3800,0000
CPU min MHz:           800,0000
BogoMIPS:              5616.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
```

The model name is correct, but I should have 4 cores, 2 threads per core (see https://ark.intel.com/products/97185/Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz). System monitor shows only one cpu and I have some issues with 100% CPU sometimes.

Secondly, I have some flickering problem during windows resizing, but the `glxinfo | grep direct` reports that the direct rendering is activated. However, the output of lspci | grep VGA is the following

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
```

and also `glxinfo | grep -i vendor` reports

```
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
```

So it seems to me that It does not recognize the NVidia GTX1050 and it uses the Intel chip.

Moreover, the touchpad is not recognized (again, common problem between ASUS users).

Could someone help me in order to check if there is something wrong with my installation? Are they related in some way? Or should I ask for a solution for each of the problem? PS Windows is running correctly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that I've found a solution. I was booting with the `"acpi=off"` option. Removing that option (actually, I don't remember why I set that option, It was due to some compatibility issue that now the upgrade solved somehow) I can see all my CPU cores and my GPU!
Hence, I suggest to upgrade and disable `acpi=off` in case of similar problems.
Moreover, now the touchpad is working, no flickering during window resizing, and the system does not hang no more on shut down, although now the shutdown slowed down a bit.